# Is it possible to call setBadgeText on pageAction in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to set the badge text for my chrome extension with the code below:

```js
chrome.pageAction.setBadgeText({"text":'3'})
```

This throws an error `Object #<Object> has no method setBadgeText`.

Comment: Page Actions do not support badge text. Have you considered using a [browser action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) instead?

Comment: yes, you are right Page Actions do not support badge text. I have used canvas to get the similar effect.

Answer (score 6):

I have used the canvas feature to get the same result. Here the code that i used.

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  chrome.pageAction.setIcon({imageData: draw(10, 0), tabId: tabId});
}, 1000);

function draw(starty, startx) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "icon_16.png"
    img.onload = function () {
       context.drawImage(img,0,2);
    }
  //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
  context.fillRect(startx % 19, starty % 19, 10, 10);
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.font = "11px Arial";
  context.fillText("3",0,19);
  return context.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19);
}
```

here you can chage the positon and color of text you want to show.

Comment: I tried to use your code, but it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null". Maybe I have to do something before using this code? F.e. create canvas element?

Comment: Just for future readers, the solution to the missing canvas problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020531/chrome-setbadgetext-on-pageaction

Answer (score 1):

**No, it is not possible with page actions**

But it is possible with browser actions.

**Excerpt:**

[page action docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction)

> Parts of the UI Like browser actions, page actions can have an icon, a
> tooltip, and popup; **they can't have badges, however**. In addition, page
> actions can be grayed out. You can find information about icons,
> tooltips, and popups by reading about the browser action UI.

What you can do is to replace the current image with another that has a badge included in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Rumor has it that you can use `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText` to set a badge on a page action. Since you can only have either a page action or a browser action in your extension, if you opt for the former this method acts on the page action even though it is part of the `browserAction` API.

Comment: Would like to hear from anybody who actually confirms this rumor. In my machine, in case of using pageAction there is no such method as chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText and apparently the question arose also from this reason.