# chrome 'setBadgeText' on pageAction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was looking how to set text to Page Action icon and found this example:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
        imageData: draw(10, 0),
        tabId: tabId
    });
}, 1000);

function draw(starty, startx) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "icon_16.png"
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 2);
    }
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
    context.fillRect(startx % 19, starty % 19, 10, 10);
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.font = "11px Arial";
    context.fillText("3", 0, 19);
    return context.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19);
}
```

But after I include it to my `eventPage.js` it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null` . Then I googled for this error and found that I have to use `getContext` only after DOM is loaded. So I wrapped above code into jQuery `.ready` function but result was the same. [image]

So I don't know where is an error now and in which way I have to search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your `canvas` element is undefined (and `undefined` has no `getContext()` method). And the cause of the problem is that there is no `canvas` element in your background page, so you need to create it first.

E.g.:

```
// Replace that line:
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

// With this line:
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

---

One more problem:

The `draw()` function returns **before** the image is loaded (and its callback executed, drawing the image onto the canvas). I have modified the code, in order to ensure that the page-action image is set **after** the image is loaded:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(setPageActionIcon);

function setPageActionIcon(tab) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.onload = function () {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 2);
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
        context.fillRect(10, 0, 19, 19);
        context.fillStyle = "white";
        context.font = "11px Arial";
        context.fillText("3", 0, 19);

        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({
            imageData: context.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19),
            tabId:     tab.id
        });
    };
    img.src = "icon16.png";
}
```

<sub>Depending on how your going to use this, there might be more efficient ways (e.g. not having to load the image every time, but keep a loaded instance around).</sub>

---

<sub>Should anyone be interested, **[here][1]** is my lame attempt to simulate a "native" Chrome badge.</sub>

Comment: Everything is ok: I see canvas, but there is no icon on the background. http://pastexen.com/i/6MFGWySBCX.png

Comment: Do you have `icon_16.png` in the same folder as your script ?

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I'll consider a way not to load image every time. But there is new issue: text isn't visible - http://pastexen.com/i/4EtXeXHwNl.png

Comment: Could it be because it is rendered on a light-colored background ? Have you tried to change `context.fillStyle = "white";` to `"black"` ? Are you using my code above or a modified version ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44891/discussion-between-vlad-golubev-and-expertsystem)